# Add timestamp to log output from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm still learning how to write bash scripts so I've pieced this script together from a few answers I've googled.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
run_receiver(){
  pushd event-receiver
  npm run clean
  npm run build
  node dist/index.js "$@"
  popd
}

run_simulator(){
  pushd simulator
  npm run clean
  npm run build
  node dist/index.js "$@"
  popd
}

run_receiver "$@" | awk '{ print "[receiver]", $0 }' 2>&1 & 
run_simulator "$@" | awk '{ print "[simulator]", $0 }' 2>&1 &
#do other things....
```

This script is running multiple node applications at the same time and prepending `[name]` on each so I can identify which command produced each log.

Now I'd like to add the date or some kind of time stamp to each line as well. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to have the `2>&1` before the `awk` since if you want to add the timestamp and name to error messages as well as standard output, that needs to happen first. Otherwise, the standard error messages won't be seen by awk. So you want:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | awk '{ print "[receiver]", $0 }' & 
run_simulator "$@" 2>&1 | awk '{ print "[simulator]", $0 }' &
```

Next, for the timestamp, you could use `date` and pass the output of `date` as a variable to `awk`:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | awk -v date="$(date)" '{ print date,"[receiver]", $0 }' &
```

But that isn't really what you want: that would calculate the date once, when `awk` is launched, so all commands would have the same date stamp. You need to have `awk` calculate the date on each input line, so you need something a bit more complex:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | 
  awk '{ com="date -Iseconds"; com | getline date; print date,"[receiver]", $0 }' &
```

That stores `date -Iseconds` in the variable `com` and then executes `com`, passing the output through awk's `getline` and storing it in the awk variable `date` which is then printed. However, the default `awk` in Ubuntu is actually `mawk` and `mawk` [buffers its input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655807/22222), so you also need to tell it not to buffer otherwise the timestamps won't be correct. So you need one more tweak:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | 
  awk -Winteractive '{ 
    com="date -Iseconds"; 
    com | getline date; 
    close(com); 
    print date,"[receiver]", $0 
}' &
```

This will produce output like this:

```
[receiver] 2022-09-23T13:33:23+03:00 line 1
[receiver] 2022-09-23T13:33:24+03:00 line 2
[receiver] 2022-09-23T13:33:25+03:00 line 3
[receiver] 2022-09-23T13:33:26+03:00 line 4
```

You can also use GNU `awk` (called `gawk` on Ubuntu) which provides some builtin functions for date manipulation:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | 
    gawk '{ date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); print "[receiver]",date,$0}'
```

Which produces output like this:

```
[receiver] 2022-09-23 13:35:42 line 1
[receiver] 2022-09-23 13:35:43 line 2
[receiver] 2022-09-23 13:35:44 line 3
[receiver] 2022-09-23 13:35:45 line 4
```

Comment: Works well, thank you for the detail and explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ts` command, from the `moreutils` package (available from the "universe" repository), incorporating your `[name]` into the optional format string to eliminate the need for `awk`. Ex.:

```
run_receiver "$@" 2>&1 | ts '[receiver] %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```